# 'MINST' downloading in Colab from pytorch's torchvision.datasets

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

The following code run in Colab and I got the following error:

> NameError: name 'MINST' is not defined

What do I need to do?

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
dataset = MINST(root='data/', download=True)
len(dataset)
test_dataset = MINST(root='data/', train=False)
len(test_dataset)
dataset[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is what it say it is a `NameError`

You imported the `MNIST` dataset and try to access `MINST` which is not a valid name.

Your code should be:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
dataset = MNIST(root='data/', download=True)
len(dataset)
test_dataset = MINST(root='data/', train=False)
len(test_dataset)
dataset[0]
```